# How do I unit test Lua modules without OO?

Tags: dependency-injection, lua, functional-programming

In Lua I can write a simple module like so

```
local database = require 'database'
local M = {}

function M:GetData()
    return database:GetData()
end

return M
```

Which when required, will load once, and all future versions will load the same copy.

If I wanted to take an object-oriented approach I could do something like:

```
local M = {}
M.__index = M

function M:GetData() 
    return self.database:GetData()
end

return function(database)
    local newM = setmetatable({}, M)
    newM.database = database
    return newM
end
```

Where M is only loaded once, and each copy of newM just holds its own data and uses the methods of the original M.

When it comes to testing, with the OO approach I can just pass in a fake version of 'database' and check it gets called, but with the first approach I can't.

So my question is how can I make the first approach support DI/testing without making it class-like?

My thought was to wrap it in a closure something like this:

```
local mClosure = function(database)
    local M = {}

    function M:GetData()
        return database:GetData()
    end

    return M
end

return mClosure
```

but then every time it is called it will create a new copy of M, so it will lose the benefits of both of the previous approaches.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your problem.  But you can temporarily replace module `database.lua` with fake one, just for testing.

Comment: How would I do that without touching the code being tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's clearly a use case for the Lua [debug library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.10). With that you can just modify the upvalues of your function and inject dependancies. Also consider that you can use `require` for this; just require your database module once, create small table that collects data and then redirects to the original module and put it in `package.loaded` so the next time you `require` it, the `require` call returns the modified version of the module. The OO approach is how you would do this kind of thing in a language like Ruby, but in Lua we have way nicer ways of tapping into a module or function without it being specifically designed for that purpose.

```
local real_db = require 'db'
local fake_db = setmetatable({}, {__index=db})
function fake_db.exec(query) print('running query: '..query) end -- dummy function
function fake_db.something(...) print('doing something'); real_db.something(...) end
package.loaded.db = fake_db
require 'my_tests' -- this in turn requires 'db', but gets the fake one
package.loaded.db = real_db
-- After this point, `require 'db'` will return the original module
```